# accessing field value inside the model in Django

Tags: python, django, database, model, default

class Products(models.Model):

```
Code = models.CharField(max_length=10,primary_key=True)
Product_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
Val_tech = models.CharField(max_length=5)
Quantity = models.IntegerField()
UOM = models.CharField(max_length=5)
Rate = models.FloatField()
Value = models.FloatField()


def __str__(self):
    return self.Product_description
```

class TableToRefer(models.Model):

```
Item = models.ForeignKey('Products.Product_description',primary_key=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Qty = models.ForeignKey('Products.Quantity',null=True,default=0,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Rate = models.ForeignKey('Products.Rate',null=True,default=0,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


price = models.FloatField(null=True,default = Rate*1.20)
```

I want to access the value of Rate field and use it in price field and automatically add the calculated price in it.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can check in your save method if your price has been set. If not, the price will be automatically calculated

```
class TableToRefer(models.Model):
    Item = models.ForeignKey('Products.Product_description',primary_key=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Qty = models.ForeignKey('Products.Quantity',null=True,default=0,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Rate = models.ForeignKey('Products.Rate',null=True,default=0,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    price = models.FloatField(null=True,default=None)

    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        if self.price is None:
            self.price = self.Rate * 0.2
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: it gives an error saying Rate is a field and cannot be multiplied.

Comment: Your rate is a foreignkey. You need to access the actual value of rate. You haven't posted the model so I we don't know which atrribute to use

Comment: I have edited my code . I added the original model which I will use only to import a csv file . How do I proceed now?

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @hendrikschneider worked for me except for the small change.

```
class TableToRefer(models.Model):
    Rate = models.FloatField(null=True,default=0)
    Item = models.ForeignKey('Products.Product_description',primary_key=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Qty = models.ForeignKey('Products.Quantity',null=True,default=0,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Rate = models.ForeignKey('Products.Rate',null=True,default=0,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    price = models.FloatField(null=True,default=None

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        if self.price is None:
            self.price = self.Rate * 0.2
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

As you can see, in the save method, you need to add self as the first parameter and it will add the value as 0.2 of rate entered.

Code Execution (attaching screenshots)

[Inserting a row in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HqMU.png)

[Output in the backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYGdz.png)